# Language to write prototype

Tags: programming-languages, data-mining

What is good language\framework for fast prototype web project with some data mining? I mean collect data from other web sites\services, working with graph data structures, morphology, calculations etc. I just want fast release my project and get answer on a question - "Is it interesting for people?". If answer is yes ok I can rewrite project in other case just forget as nightmare. I'm asp.net webforms\mvc developer but looking at ruby on rails. I think asp.net is good for project in a long time but a little over verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just building prototype i advice you to get the thing done fast with the language you are most comfortable with. Or you can just outsource it, i remember a [link](http://iwbyp.chris-granger.com/) i've seen in hacker news few days back

Answer (score 2):

I like Python/Django because you get access to all of Python's libraries, which include some very good ones for data mining/machine learning stuff such as sciPy/numPy and networkX.